# FMDB (SQL) tried to got array from database (iOS)

Tags: ios, database, fmdb

I need to load database: **shortSelected - string, array - array of strings, date - date**.

I load database from *shortSelected*(it string that always different) and database has all that values, I pass *shortSelected* to database, but in 3 string `resultSet=nil`. What is  wrong?

```
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase sharedInstance];
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
FMResultSet *resultSet = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM rss WHERE name = shortSelected"];
NSArray *resultArray = [resultSet objectForColumnName:@"array"];
NSDate *resultDate = [resultSet dateForColumn:@"date"];
[results addObject:resultArray];
[results addObject:resultDate];
self.data = results;
NSLog(@"%@", _data[0][shortSelected]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `next` method to confirm whether there is data in the set, then to read the data. code should be

```
while([resultSet next])
{
   NSArray *resultArray = [resultSet objectForColumnName:@"array"];
   NSDate *resultDate = [resultSet dateForColumn:@"date"];
   [results addObject:resultArray];
   [results addObject:resultDate];
}
```